# Typo3 RealURL: UID with leading zeros

Tags: php, typo3, realurl, leading-zero

Assuming the following Typo3 RealURL setup:

```
'news' => array(
        array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
        ),
        array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
        ),
        array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'CONCAT(title, "-", uid)',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                'strtolower' => 1,
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        ),
                        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                        'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                        'autoUpdate' => 1,
                        'expireDays' => 180,
                ),
        ),
),
```

It's about this line: `'alias_field' => 'CONCAT(title, "-", uid)',`

I need to add leading zeros to `uid`, so it has at least three digits.

Outside of an array, it would be: `$uid = sprintf('%03d', $uid);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MySQL function [LPAD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

It will look something like this:

```
'alias_field' => "CONCAT(title, '-', LPAD(uid, 3,'0'))",
```